# && operator in if statement with for in loop is not giving right answer

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have cart system for a website I made. I'm currently trying to create a discount deal  in the checkout page. I've put together an if statement but its not quite working. see below:

```js
for (var i in cartArray) {
   if((cartArray[i].name=="Shampoo") &&
   (cartArray[i].name=="Drinks Can") &&
   (cartArray[i].name=="Small Brush"))
   {
   console.log("yes");
   } else {
   console.log("no");
   
   }
  }
```

I get '5 no' in the console but when I use the OR operator it works. But that won't do as I need the code to recognize all 3 simultaneously so I can proceed further with the discount. Thank you in advance.

ps. heres what the console looks like in full:

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {name: "500ml Conditioner", price: 1.5, count: 1, total: "1.50"}
1: {name: "1.5L Bleach", price: 2.5, count: 1, total: "2.50"}
2: {name: "Small Brush", price: 2.5, count: 1, total: "2.50"}
3: {name: "Shampoo", price: 4, count: 1, total: "4.00"}
4: {name: "Drinks Can", price: 1, count: 1, total: "1.00"}
```

Comment: Hello, this question is too broad to be able to answer. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How would that condition ever evaluate to `true`? You're asking for the *same* property to be simultaneously equal to three different things at the same time.

Comment: What is the condition to the discount be applied? This discount will be applied to the item or to the final value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check item names as you iterate through your cart. Right now, though, you're checking all three possible names against the same item (`cartArray[i].name`) on each pass. So your code will never return 'yes' because the same item can never have three different names.

One way to fix this might be to use three booleans that start false and get set to true when a name matches. For example:

```
var shampoo = false;
var drinks = false;
var brush = false;

for (var i in cartArray) {
    switch (cartArray[i].name) {
        case "Shampoo":
            shampoo = true;
            break;
        case "Drinks Can":
            drinks = true;
            break;
        case "Small Brush":
            brush = true;
            break;
    }
    if (shampoo && drinks && brush) {
        console.log("yes");
        break;
    }
}
if (!shampoo || !drinks || !brush) {
    console.log("no");
}
```

Instead of testing on every loop, you could also test only when a boolean is set true, checking whether the other two are already true. You could also use `if ... else if ...` if you prefer it to `switch`. Plenty of ways to accomplish what you want.

Comment: thanks, great explanation and a little daft on my part. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but your current statement ask for the i-th item of the cart array to be named Shampoo, Drinks Can and Small Brush at the same time with the AND operator. Either use a switch statement for your purpose or consequent if-s. You could do something like:

```
for (var i in cartArray) 
{
     switch cartArray[i]:
        case "Shampoo":
             // do what you need
             break;
        case "Drinks Can"
             // do something
             break;
        default: console.log("no")    
}
```

Read about switch statement [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)